# SQL Server XQuery, how do i select a value

Tags: sql, xquery

I have `XML` type column in my SQL Server table, and the XML document that is in that table looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>  
<Product xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">    
    <Key xmlns="urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/page/product">48;nyI9AAJ7/1AAVQBCADYAAAACe/8xAC4AMAAwAAAAAIfei8sC11;152438283530;</Key>    
    <Code xmlns="urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/page/product">PR238</Code>    
    <Version xmlns="urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/page/product">1.00</Version>    
    <ExternalRefNr xmlns="urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/page/product">46894046</ExternalRefNr>    
    <Name xmlns="urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/page/product">Nailgun XJ-3</Name>  
</Product>
```

Now, in a SQL Server (X) Query I want to select the name of this product (Nailgun XJ-3), but whatever I try, I always get an empty result.

I guess it should be something simple, like the line below, but I'm missing something. Perhaps it's the handling of the namespace, but I couldn't find a proper way to do that.

```
SELECT ProductDetailSourceXML.query('//Name') FROM Product
```

Comment: Try using //*:Name to specify that there is a namespace associated with the element.

Comment: Using //*: results in nothing. Using //microsoft-dynamics-schemas/page/product:Name  results in 'microsoft-dynamics-schemas/page/product does not denote a namespace.' (error translated from german error message)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's the XML namespace - since it's there, you must respect it and deal with it properly!

Try this:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT NOT NULL, ProductsDetailXML XML)

INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES(1, N'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>  
<Product xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">    
    <Key xmlns="urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/page/product">48;nyI9AAJ7/1AAVQBCADYAAAACe/8xAC4AMAAwAAAAAIfei8sC11;152438283530;</Key>    
    <Code xmlns="urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/page/product">PR238</Code>    
    <Version xmlns="urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/page/product">1.00</Version>    
    <ExternalRefNr xmlns="urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/page/product">46894046</ExternalRefNr>    
    <Name xmlns="urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/page/product">Nailgun XJ-3</Name>  
</Product>')

-- define the XML namespace and a prefix to use in your XQuery    
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES('urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/page/product' AS ns)
SELECT
    ID,
    -- use the XML namespace prefix where needed!
    ProductName = XC.value('(ns:Name)[1]', 'varchar(50)')
FROM 
    @tbl
CROSS APPLY 
    ProductsDetailXML.nodes('/Product') AS XT(XC)
WHERE
    ID = 1
```

Comment: Your example works just fine, but on my database i still get an empty result.

Comment: Could the problem be some setting on database level?